# Discord API (JDA) Get a user from specific Guild

Tags: java

```
try {
    final JDABuilder jdaBuilder = JDABuilder.createDefault(TOKEN_ID);
    jdaBuilder.addEventListeners(new DiscordListener());
    _jdaBuild = jdaBuilder.build();
} catch(final LoginException e) {

}
```

I tried use the

```
_jdaBuild.getUserById(userId);
```

But it always return null. I also tried do a for to all Guild then to all Text Channels and then to All members but in log it only show the ID of the Bot from all Text Channels. Not the other users.

How can i get user base on his ID or Name from a Guild and send him a private?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`JDA#retrieveUserById​(long)`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#retrieveUserById(long)) because [`JDA#getUserById(long)`](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/JDA.html#getUserById(long)) only works if the user is cached:

```
try {
    final JDABuilder jdaBuilder = JDABuilder.createDefault(TOKEN_ID);
    jdaBuilder.addEventListeners(new DiscordListener());
    _jdaBuild = jdaBuilder.build();
} catch(final LoginException e) {
    //...
}
//...
User user = _jdaBuild.retrieveUserById("...").complete();
```